# Why my assertEquals doesn't work?

Tags: java, junit

I am testing one of my methods, `double getSqrt(double s)`, and having the following JUnit test code:

```java
@Test
public void testGetSqrt() {
    System.out.println("getSqrt");
    double s = 16.0;
    Calculator instance = new Calculator();
    double expResult = 4.0;
    double result = 4.000000000052429; // was "instance.getSqrt(s);" here
                                       // now hardcode for test purpose
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
    assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);
}
```

It failed every time, no matter how I changed the tolerance "0.0", "0.1", "0.00", "0.01", "0.001".... The report is the following:

> AssertionFailedError: expected:<4.0>; but was:<4.000000000052429>

What I am using is JUnit 4.12 and Hamcrest 1.3.

And my imports:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Did I use the tolerance wrong?

Output on the console:

```
compile-test-single:
Testsuite: descriptivestatisticsapplication.processing.CalculatorTest
getSqrt
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.079 sec

------------- Standard Output ---------------

getSqrt

C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Users\Z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DescriptiveStatisticsApplication\build\classes;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\modules\ext\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\modules\ext\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DescriptiveStatisticsApplication\build\test\classes;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\extide\ant\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\extide\ant\lib\ant.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\extide\ant\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\extide\ant\lib\ant-junit4.jar

------------- ---------------- ---------------
```

Update on 5/27:

After doing some tests from the suggestions in the comments, this unit test can now pass successfully. I think this question can be closed.

What I worry about is I didn't find out any reason why it failed and why now it succeed! Same code, same logic! The only thing I have done is like commenting out some non-important lines and then adding them back, changing some declaration statements sequence and then changing them back. The same code has different behaviors. I haven't changed anything in the building and running env and libs. This doesn't make any sense. The result from a piece of code should be reproducible.

Comment: inside of your `getSqrt` method, how are you calculating the square root?

Comment: @BiancaRosa Does it matter? We can see the results.

Comment: @BiancaRosa The implementation of getSqrt should not be relevant. As you can see it has already worked out the result <4.000000000052429>. It is not precise of course because I am using Double. The problem is, I have limited the precision tolerance to like 0.01 but it still doesn't work. I can't figure out why...

Comment: What do you get if you replace `instance.getSqrt(s)` with `4.000000000052429` hardcoded?

Comment: Insted of playing with precision, you should use library when this kind of problems are already solved. Like Hamcrest matchers, or assertJ ...

Comment: @Pang Just tried hardcode, same result.

Comment: Then can you please **[edit]** and update your question by replacing `instance.getSqrt(s)` with `4.000000000052429`? By moving your code towards a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you can help us solve your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show how your imports look like? Do you import assertEquals like: import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
Or maybe it comes from somwhere else?

Comment: @gawi Yes, exactly.

Comment: Can't reproduce (as I expected). Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Also, add `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));`to the test, and post the output.

Comment: @JBNizet Output posted.

Comment: Still no complete minimal example reproducing the problem (the only code you posted isn't complete, uses unknown classes, and uses 0.0 as tolerance, which of course can't work). And still no output for the classpath, as I requested.

Comment: @JBNizet The test is now past without finding any reason.

Comment: @JBNizet BTW, I normally use 0.1 or 0.01 like to test. It is the failure that made me try 0.0. As you can see in my previous description I did use 0.1.

Answer (score -1):

The float in Java is not precise and as you've already seen the result <4.000000000052429>
In other words, you set a float number to 4 in java, it is not actually 4.
You can use long or even BigInteger to solve this problem.

Comment: That's what the tolerance does-gives you a margin of error.